# What is the `Authorization` part of the http post request of Google's Firebase Downstream message?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to try to send a message using google's `FCM` messaging service and as the document says, the http request should be something like this:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

My problem is that I have not idea what `Authorization`'s value should be and when I delete this header and make the request, I get error `401:Unauthorized`.I think this must be some kind of api key or something but I cannot find it in my project. Can anyone help me?

PS: for testing purposes I currently am using [this site](http://requestmaker.com/) to send a messsage to my device

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to [About Firebase Cloud Messaging Server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-http-connection-server-protocol) documentation:

> Authentication
>
> To send a message, the app server issues a POST request. For example:
>
> `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`
>
> A message request consists of two parts: the HTTP header and the HTTP
> body.
>
> The HTTP header must contain the following headers:
>
> - Authorization: key=YOUR_SERVER_KEY

Make sure this is the **server** key, whose value is available in your Firebase project console under **Project Settings** > **Cloud Messaging**. Client keys or any other keys are rejected by FCM.

> - Content-Type: `application/json` for JSON; `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8` for plain text.
>
>   ```
>    If Content-Type is omitted, the format is assumed to be plain text.
>   ```

---

***UPDATE (2016/11/16)***

Perhaps you should consider using the FCM token instead of the server keys as the note inside the following screenshot

[image]

---

***UPDATE (2016/12/08)***

Firebase has upgraded the server keys to a new version and recommended that you upgrade to the newest version. Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. The documentation is not well-organized in my opinion, but thank you again for your answer

Comment: Hey @BNK would you mind posting example curl or httpie code? I can't seem to get the Authorization to work. Thanks!

Comment: @FredLoh at the Google's link in my answer, at "Checking the validity of a server key", you will find curl example

Comment: I am getting HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request my post is fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send Content-Type:application/json Authorization:key=GduFdg......wK8B4Uwk2xxx... { "data": { "message": "post message", "version" : "2.0: }, "to" : "fasdsadasdsadasj9N40:APA91b....5nX--HG.....7wyTCN" } what is wrong?

Comment: @SagarPatil you got 400, not 401 as the OP, so fyi https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes

Answer (score 2):

i have also faced this error. The issue is with the server key. Don't use the api key from google-services.json file.

You should use the server api key from your firebase console project, at the cloud messaging tab project keys: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/firebase-probiz/settings/cloudmessaging

Answer (score 0):

This is your Server key which you can observe into console.developers.google.com or Firebase project console under Project Settings > Cloud Messaging. Note the key it's auto created by Google Services. You ought add IP Address inco G.Console to restrict usage.

Plus do remember about Content-Type: application/json, otherwise you will get Error=MissingRegistration.