# The request was missing an Authentication Key (FCM Token). Where to find that key?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

Sorry. Newbie here. Would like to ask where or what is that Auth Key? I tried using Web API Key, Google PLIST API_KEY and cloud messaging server keys.

[image]

[image: Reponse]

Comment: You need to specify the FCM server/authorization key, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673205/what-is-the-authorization-part-of-the-http-post-request-of-googles-firebase-d and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427709/firebase-messaging-where-to-get-server-key

Comment: I don't know if I need to delete this. Just to reiterate the solution: `Authorization: key=WEB SERVER KEY`

Comment: I use "Legacy server key" as Authorization key, which you can find it from firbase console, select your project and  Settings->CLOUD MESSAGING(second tab)->Project credentials->Legacy server key